# Merge multiple CLI EXEs into a single EXE?

Tags: windows, merge, binary-files

I currently use three command-line Windows applications to backup, zip, and upload files: HoboCopy.exe, 7za.exe, and ncftpput.exe.

I was wondering if there were a way to somehow merge/combine those binaries into a single EXE without access to their source code.

I vaguely remember using an application years ago that could do this for DLLs, ie. merge an EXE and the DLLs it depended on, but can it be done with EXEs?

Thank you.

Comment: It can be done using a self-extracting exe, but that would mean it has to extract itself every time you want to run the program(s). What is the reason you want to group them as one exe?

Comment: Thanks. As an easier way to distribute the apps.

Comment: Given that you do not make these apps, are you aware that the software might not be distributed like that?

Comment: Consider the licensing implications carefully before you try to bundle other applications like this. (I think that's what @LPChip is hinting at)

Comment: Yup. :) That's what I'm hinting at.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [bat2exe](http://bat2exe.net)?
Create a new directory, copy in your executables, then add the following batch script with any name:

```
@echo off
dir /b *.exe
echo Enter what to execute:
set /p exec=
%exec%.exe
pause
```

Follow on-screen instruction from bat2exe.
This may not be the most elegant solution, but should still work.